# tnsping to database is too high from the same server as database

Tags: database, oracle

I have been struggling with this and did not find any good solution online. We have a test JIRA application on a server with it's database also on the same server. The problem with connectivity from the application to the database started happening after a change was made to the server name. So, we updated the tnsnames.ora file with the new server name. After this, however, the tnsping to the database is taking very long time. I am tnspinging from the same server. I reinstalled the listener just to be sure that the listener is not using the old server name somehow. But still no luck. We updated tnsnames to use the ip of the server or just 127.0.0.1 instead but still the same issue. I am able to connect to the database but it takes a while before it connects to it. I did a tracert to the server and ip and got a response in 1 msec. I also checked that the log file of the listener is not very big in size. It was about 500 MB and I renamed the old file to something. It created a new log.xml file again.
Following are the listener details:

```
C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator>lsnrctl status

LSNRCTL for 64-bit Windows: Version 11.2.0.1.0 - Production on 28-MAR-2014 12:43
:31

Copyright (c) 1991, 2010, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Connecting to (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=10.100.10.17)(PORT=1521)
))
STATUS of the LISTENER
------------------------
Alias                     LISTENER
Version                   TNSLSNR for 64-bit Windows: Version 11.2.0.1.0 - Produ
ction
Start Date                27-MAR-2014 18:39:36
Uptime                    0 days 18 hr. 4 min. 44 sec
Trace Level               off
Security                  ON: Local OS Authentication
SNMP                      OFF
Listener Parameter File   E:\app\Administrator\product\11.2.0\dbhome_1\network\a
dmin\listener.ora
Listener Log File         e:\app\administrator\diag\tnslsnr\qa-misc\listener\ale
rt\log.xml
Listening Endpoints Summary...
  (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=qa-misc)(PORT=1521)))
  (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=ipc)(PIPENAME=\\.\pipe\EXTPROC1521ipc)))
Services Summary...
Service "CLRExtProc" has 1 instance(s).
  Instance "CLRExtProc", status UNKNOWN, has 2 handler(s) for this service...
Service "confluence" has 1 instance(s).
  Instance "confluence", status READY, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
Service "confluenceXDB" has 1 instance(s).
  Instance "confluence", status READY, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
Service "fisheyetest" has 1 instance(s).
  Instance "fisheyetest", status READY, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
Service "fisheyetestXDB" has 1 instance(s).
  Instance "fisheyetest", status READY, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
Service "testjira" has 1 instance(s).
  Instance "testjira", status READY, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
Service "testjiraXDB" has 1 instance(s).
  Instance "testjira", status READY, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
The command completed successfully
```

Following are the results of the tnsping to the database:

```
C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator>tnsping testjira 8

TNS Ping Utility for 64-bit Windows: Version 11.2.0.1.0 - Production on 28-MAR-2
014 12:32:48

Copyright (c) 1997, 2010, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Used parameter files:
E:\app\Administrator\product\11.2.0\dbhome_1\network\admin\sqlnet.ora


Used TNSNAMES adapter to resolve the alias
Attempting to contact (DESCRIPTION = (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = 127.0.0.
1)(PORT = 1521)) (CONNECT_DATA = (SERVER = DEDICATED) (SERVICE_NAME = testjira))
)
OK (30 msec)
OK (10020 msec)
OK (40000 msec)
OK (10030 msec)
OK (10010 msec)
OK (10020 msec)
OK (10020 msec)
OK (10010 msec)
```

Comment: Can you post the contents of the sqlnet.ora file that is referenced in the output of your `tnsping` command?

Comment: what about the time with ip "ping" and if you run nslookup on the machine, see how long the dns takes.

Comment: Make a copy of your sqlnet.ora file and remove it. Now try tnsping.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on DBA.stackexchange.com